# R - Get joint probabilities from 2D Kernel Density Estimate

Tags: r, probability-density

I have two vectors S and V, and using the function `kde2d`, I get the following plot of their joint density:

[image: Joint probability density of <code>S</code> and <code>V</code>]

Using this data, is it possible to obtain an empirical estimate of the joint probability, in the form P(S[i],V[j]) ?

In the question [How to find/estimate probability density function from density function in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78711/how-to-find-estimate-probability-density-function-from-density-function-in-r) it is suggested we use `approxfun` to get the height of a value in a 1D KDE plot. Is there a way to extend this idea to 2 dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) of the grid returned by `kde2d`:

```
library(fields)
points <- data.frame(x=0:2, y=c(0, 5, 5))
interp.surface(k, points)
# [1] 0.066104795 0.040191482 0.001943069
```

Data:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(144)
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- 5*x + rnorm(1000)
k <- kde2d(x, y)
```